# Floyd-Steinberg dithering algorithm getting out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem with Floyd-Steinberg dithering algorithm in Python. It keeps getting out of bounds on its width. I've checked many sources and I can't figure out where is the mistake... Here is my code:

```
def floydSteinberg(src, colorPalette):
src = src.copy()
h,w = src.shape[:2]
for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        oldpixel = src[x][y]
        newpixel = colorFit(oldpixel, colorPalette)
        src[x][y] = newpixel
        quant_error = oldpixel - newpixel
        if (x<w-1):
            src[x+1][y] = src[x+1][y] + quant_error * 7/16
        if (x>0) and (y<h-1):
            src[x-1][y+1] = src[x-1][y+1] + quant_error * 3/16
        if (y<h-1):
            src[x][y+1] = src[x][y+1] + quant_error * 5/16
        if (x<w-1) and (y<h-1):
            src[x+1][y+1] = src[x+1][y+1] + quant_error * 1/16     
return src
```

And the error:

> line 33, in floydSteinberg
> src[x][y+1] = src[x][y+1] + quant_error * 5/16
> IndexError: index 180 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 180

Tested image is 180px wide.
I also tried substracting 1 from w or h in for loop, but it does not help at all (just to see if that will do something)

Comment: `y+1` I'm pretty sure is out of bounds. Maybe do `range(h-1)`?

Comment: As I wrote, it does not change anything

Comment: Zliczamy stany...

Comment: voting to close this question since it's due to a **typo**. you mixed up the indices to the array. it's `[y,x]` or `[y][x]`, but **not** `[x,y]` or `[x][y]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your height and width seem to be swapped. Try changing:

```
h,w = src.shape[:2]
```

to:

```
w, h = src.shape[:2]
```

and it should work.

Comment: **that's even wronger**. the shape of a numpy array, when interpreted as an image, is `(height, width, channels)` or `(height, width)`. do not intentionally mix up the naming. I can't fathom how anyone would think that this was a good idea to give as an answer, except that it's a quick dirty hack that won't teach OP what the real mistake is. -- OP's issue is that he mixed up the indices to the array. it's `[y,x]` or `[y][x]`, but **not** `[x,y]` or `[x][y]`. I've voted to close this question as a typo.